# How to have a different AjaxComplete for each ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a different loading symbol show and hide depending on the ajax call.. Since I'm only showing a default loading symbol which is a fixed window with a loading symbol on the center.

The problem is I have too many ajax calls that do different things around my website, most of the calls require only a very small loading symbol here and there, not really a fixed window with the symbol on the center.

I got nothing, since I haven't found anything. I'll prefarably do this with plain JS instead of jQuery, although I'll use whatever it works.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can make the logic on the ajax methods; beforeSend and done. Also create a variable named loadingType which will determine what component on the page to show/hide depending on the call.

```js
function doAjax(url, loadType){
 $.ajax({
  url: "your-url",
  beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
   switch(loadType){
    // based on loadType variable you display the correct loading element
   }
  }
 })
 .done(function( data ) {
  // When finished, hide all the loading elements
 });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just tried your method but it doesn't work as a ajaxComplete.. It just work if the button the triggers the ajax request is clicked carefully, meaning that if I click the button simultaneously, it will trigger multiple calls and the loading symbol won't hide.. That's the main problem, that the loading symbol just won't hide if I trigger a call simultaneously. It's weird!